# Groovy: Inherit trait method

Tags: groovy, traits

So I have the following case:

```
trait JsonRepresentable { 
     def foo() { print "json" }
}

class SuperA implements JsonRepresentable { }
class SuperB implements JsonRepresentable { }

class Child1 extends SuperA {}
class Child2 extends SuperB { }
```

Now, if I call the foo() method on SuperA or SuperB it works fine. However if I inherit from them the foo() method is not implemented on the child classes.

```
Groovy:Can't have an abstract method in a non-abstract class. The class 'Child1' must be declared abstract or the method 'foo()' must be implemented.
```

It can be solved if I implement the JsonRepresentable trait on the child too, but its already defined on the super class so I guess there is a way to inherit the trait's foo method some way. Can you help me how to do that?

**Edit**: 
Groovy version: 2.3.10

Comment: Works for me, Groovy 2.4.3

Comment: The example code works for me in the groovyConsole for Groovy 2.3.10 as well

Comment: ie:  I can call `new Child1().foo()` and it prints out `json`

Comment: You are right. I checked now and the given simplifyed example works for me too. The problem is in the real code, but only eclipse gives me the error, I can run the code and it works correctly. So I suspect the problem is in the groovy eclipse plugin I'm using. I'll try to update it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was not in groovy. It was the eclipse groovy plugin (or compiler) which marked the build erroneously. I couldn't solve the compilation issue, but it runs fine when I start the application, so it's ok with me.

Comment: I have a grails 3.3.5 app that comes with groovy 2.4.15 and I have the same exact problem. I have tried commenting out the apply plugin: "eclipse" line from the build.gradle without any luck. Any idea of what I got to do?

Comment: Sorry I don't remember how to fix it. I don't use eclipse anymore, too many of these kind of errors.